# SaveChanges() operation updates only "memory" values

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, updates

I use simple Console application with database and generated .edmx file. When I insert new row and track update I see that all is ok. But when I go to view the content of my database I dont see any changes.All looks like I was updated "memory instance" of my database.What should I change in my ConnectionString OR/AND .edmx file for updating real database?
**UPDATE**

```
    <connectionStrings>
            <add name="ProductsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Products.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var context = new ProductsEntities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProductsEntities"].ConnectionString);
         var productForInsert = new Product {CompanyName = "Insert Name", Price = new decimal(22), Description = "dd", Name = "ddd"};
         context.Products.AddObject(productForInsert);
         context.SaveChanges();
         // return only new row as expected ([database rows].CompanyName == "Toshiba")
         // tracking database rows returns expected result too
         var result = context.Products.Where(p => p.CompanyName != "Toshiba");
         foreach (var b in result)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(b.CompanyName);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using ObjectContext or DbContext? Are you sure your edmx file and connection string are used at all? If you are using DbContext and CodeFirst something does not seem to be configured correctly and EF ignores your edmx file (and connection string) and creates the database for itself. So you are effectively not looking at the right database. Post some code to show what you are doing.

Comment: I use ObjectContext (autogenerated .edmx file from existing database in the root of application).I'll update my question with code a bit later (currently I havent got access to it).I am sure that it used correctly as I can read existing rows from database.

Comment: Use a profiler (i.e. Sql Server Profiler if you are using Sql Server) to verify you see queries being sent to the database.

Comment: Thanks,I forgot this popular tool.

Comment: Are the application and you looking to the same database? May sound stupid but there are many similar issues where finally two database appeared to be around.